# Debugger is not hitting, though Xdebug is installed

Tags: php, eclipse, xdebug

I have enabled Xdbug from php.ini. How do i enable debugging from eclipse. I set the debugger in eclipse but they are never hit, each time when ever it try to debug a new configuration is created.

[image]

[image]

debugger setting:
[image]

Comment: It's best if you launch the debugger for the main site and navigate to your page instead of creating new sessions for each page. Create a server once, and then use that an navigate

Comment: Does my debug setting looks ok ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved it ,
following lines were commented.
        xdebug.remote_enable=true
        xdebug.remote_host=localhost
        xdebug.remote_port=10000
        xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
        xdebug.profiler_enable=1
        xdebug.profiler_output_dir="C:\xampp\tmp"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your debugger session is already running. That's why you're getting that message. Eclipse usually switches to the Debug perspective when you hit debug. You can manually switch to it by clicking on the Open Perspective button.

[image: Open Perspective]

If you're working with vhosts, make sure to create a new Server with that hostname. Go to `Windows -> Preferences` and then `PHP -> Debug`. Select the `PHP Servers` option and create a new server with your vhost.

After that, create a new Run Configuration with your newly created server. Once you've created the configuration, you can simply run it. You can also quick access it by going to `Run -> Debug History`. It will only show up in history once you've run it at least once.

Comment: Can you help me in creating vhost.

Comment: I only added the vhost comment because you seem to be using vhosts. How do you usually access your projects? `http://localhost/project`? or something else?

Comment: when developing , right on the page and click on debug button.

Comment: Does my debug setting looks ok ?

Comment: @Huzaifa no, I mean how do you access your site? Do you run your project locally? If so how do you access it in your browser? You seem to have switched off some useful information (not required, but useful). Did you follow the steps in the article I posted in the earlier question? That helped me setup without any problems at all